# Django __in but return the first matching element

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have this model

```py
from django.db import models

class TranslatedString(models.Model):
    lang = models.CharField()
    key = models.CharField()
    value = models.CharField()
```

I have these instances of this model:

```py
a = TranslatedString(lang="en_US", key="my-string", value="hello world")
b = TranslatedString(lang="en_AU", key="my-string", value="g'day world")
c = TranslatedString(lang="ja_JP", key="my-string", value="こんにちは世界")
```

And I have this list of languages a user wants

```py
preferred_langs = ["en_CA", "en_US", "en_AU", "fr_CA"]
```

which is ordered by preference. I would like to return the value that matches the first item in that list. Even though both `a` and `b` would match a query like

```py
TranslatedString.objects.filter(key="my-string", lang__in=preferred_langs).first()
```

I want it to be ordered by the list, so that I always get `a`.

I can make a query for each element in `preferred_langs` and return as soon as I find a matching value, but is there a better option? I'd like to do it in one query.

Comment: This may be challenging to express using the ORM. If the overhead of retrieving multiple objects from the database would not be an issue, resolving the query set and then sorting the retrieved models in Python might be the simplest approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generator expression over `preferred_langs` to produce a mapping of preferred languages to their respective indices in the list as `When` objects for a `Case` object to be annotated as a field so that you can order the filtered result by it:

```
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When

TranslatedString.objects.filter(key="my-string", lang__in=preferred_langs).annotate(
    preference=Case(*(When(lang=lang, then=Value(i)) for i, lang in preferred_langs))
).order_by('preference').first()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind retrieving all preferred translations from the database, this may be accomplished tersely by sorting the models in Python:

```
preferred_langs = ["en_CA", "en_US", "en_AU", "fr_CA"]
strings = list(TranslatedString.objects.filter(key="my-string", lang__in=preferred_langs))

strings.sort(key=lambda s: preferred_langs.index(s))
first_choice = strings[0]

print(first_choice.lang)  # outputs "en_US"
```

This will perform a single (but potentially large) query. However, if the sequence of preferred languages is fairly short, the sorting should occur in negligible time.